# Animating Latitude and Longitude points - how to do it? What tools?

Tags: after-effects, flash

This is my first go at asking a video production related question...

I have a programming / data science background.

I have about 30,000 spatial co-ordinates (i.e x , y coordinates) These have come into existence over about 15 years.  I want to animate this.

So, I need a programmatic approach - there are just too many points.

Also, when each point appears...I want it to initially appear at say 100% opacity and then over about 15 frames fade to about 30% opacity.

What tool is the best to do this in...?

I am not sure if After Effects has sufficient programatic control..?

What about Flash..?  (i.e Adobe CC Animate).

Eventually, I want this animated series of points to be a layer and I will stick it on top of a base map. And do some other stuff.  So eventually, the layers will be composited in After Effects.

What tool should I use to create this animation...?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: The points should appear and disappear? In addition to micheals answer, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/is-there-a-tool-for-scientific-visualization-using-blender

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/), which uses Python as a scripting language.  This gives you a powerful way to "fly" through the data as it animates.

If you are happy with just a static perspective of the map with the points being animated, [R](https://www.r-project.org/) has an extraordinary range of graphing capabilties that can be used to generate animations.

Comment: Thanks MT.   I have a Maya license.  I was thinking of using this but the result will be in 2D not 3D....

Comment: Yes, R is pretty cool.  But eventually I want the output in HD video.  At the moment...I am thinking that Adobe Animate CC might be the best.

Answer (score 1):

I often use [Processing](http://processing.org) for simple graphics or scripting projects, which would be difficult to achieve with After Effects expressions. If you prefer coding in C++ to Java, you could look at [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc) which is a similar tool. Both are designed to make it easy to experiment visually while using the data processing tools of a coding environment.

tomh mentioned the GeoLayers plugin for After Effects but, while it's a really nice tool, I'm not sure it's designed to deal with data sets like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the After Effects plugin [GeoLayers](http://aescripts.com/geolayers/), or if you need something more advanced, maybe [DEM Earth](https://cinemaplugins.com/c4d-plugins/dem-earth/) in Cinema4D instead.

Comment: Thanks very much @tomh I had a look at the plugs ins and their awesome.  But I am not sure whether they will help me solve my specific problem.  Basically, at a particular time (say 13 secs 24 frames) I want a specific point (say x = 13, y = 130) to display a dot.  Ideally, this do would have some type of basic animation such as fade in / fade out.  All this needs to be done programmatically as there will be perhaps 100,000 points.

Comment: @markthekoala, [AE scripts](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/scripts.html) (basically it's JS) are not limited to expressions. I wrote a simple point coordinates exporting script back in the day. Surely you can implement the reverse problem. The only open question is can AE handle 30000 layers in one composition.